# I have an issue to publish app to the app store

Tags: app-store

I have an issue with the app store , can anyone tell me what is my mistake?
3 months ago,I have published my app which saves video from youtube and it got rejected from the app store.and I know I break the privacy for the youtube this is no problem because it's my fault .

Now after 3 months,I am trying to publish another app which allow user to download music mp3 from any website (youtube , Facebook,twitter not including) also it get the rejected they tell me,I must take permission.
How can I take permission from all websites? What is my mistake? I think my app is not breaking any privacy.
and I search in app store I found many apps that allow user to download from youtube.

please any help about this issue and what I do so I can let apple publish my app?

thank a lot

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the app store's TOS, not about programming per se.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have permission to download videos from Youtube, Facebook etc. Just because there are other apps on the store that have these features doesn't mean that it's allowed.

Comment: I know i have no permission to download from youtube and facebook , etc my app download mp3 from websites in google so i wondered why also rejected

Comment: You also don't have permission to download them from those other sites I assume? Because you had an earlier negative approach (when you had an app for downloading from youtube) Apple won't give you the benefit of the doubt anymore I assume.

Comment: Ok my brother , you are right thank you very much

Comment: Good luck with your future apps!